# C++ stable_sort not stable?

Tags: c++, stl, stable-sort

I am using C++ stable_sort to sort a vector of my class objects in ascending order using a comparator function, but the sort is not stable. A work around that worked was to reverse iterate and reversing the logic in the comparator. But cant understand why it shouldnt work normally.
Code:

```
using namespace std;
class Pair{
    string str;
    int num;
public:
    Pair(string s, int n):str(s), num(n)
    {}
    Pair(const Pair &a)
    {
        str = a.str;
        num = a.num;
    }
    int Num()
    {
        return num;
    }
    string Str() const{
        return str;
    }
    void set(string s, int n)
    {
        str = s;
        num=n;
    }
    void print() const{
        cout<<"\n"<<num<<" "<<str;
    }
};

bool comparator( Pair a,  Pair b)
{
    return a.Num()<=b.Num();
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<Pair> arr;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < n; a0++){
        int x;
        string s;
        cin >> x >> s;
        if((a0+1)<=n/2)
            s="-";
        Pair p(s, x);
        arr.push_back(p);
    }
    cout<<"\n Before sort";
    for(auto i:arr)
        i.print();

    stable_sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), comparator);
    cout<<"\n\n After sort";
    for(auto i:arr)
        i.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:
Before sort
0 -
6 -
0 -
6 -
4 -
0 -
6 -
0 -
6 -
0 -
4 that
3 be
0 to
1 be
5 question
1 or
2 not
4 is
2 to
4 the

After sort
0 to
0 -
0 -
0 -
0 -
0 -
1 or
1 be
2 to
2 not
3 be
4 the
4 is
4 that
4 -
5 question
6 -
6 -
6 -
6 -

Comment: Could you provide your desired output (by editing the question)?

Comment: Please run your program, give it input and see its output. Then copy-paste that input and output directly from the console window into the question. And add what output you *expected*.

Comment: `comp(a,a)` shall be false. See the relevant [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare).

Comment: `stable_sort` *is* stable, provided your comparison function plays by the rules and implement a *strict weak ordering* - if you don't do that all bets are off.

Answer (score 7):

> comp  -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

from [stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort). The comparator must implement a *strict weak ordering*. See also [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for a table of the exact requirements.

Your comparator is wrong, it also returns true for equal elements.

Comment: You may want to mention "strict weak ordering" / "strict total ordering" and perhaps quote a definition.

Comment: Thanks Yassin, that was the problem. sorted.